# Calling Global Variable by Its Name in R

Tags: r, global-variables

I am aware that this is how we get the global variable names in R:

```
var <- as.list(.GlobalEnv)    
var_names <- names(var)
```

Once you get the names, is there a way to call the variables using var_names?
For instance, if `var_names[1] = "a"`, I would want to write `function(var_name[1])` and have it refer to `a`.

Comment: Use `get()` to refer to data by its variable name. Use `assign()` to assign values to variable by its name. For instance, `assign("Peace",1)` makes a variable `Peace` which contains `1`. Then do `get("Peace")`

Comment: use `mget` if you want to refer to several object

Comment: @cderv didn't know that...thanks

Comment: In your example, there's no need to bother with `get`, just do `var[[var_names[1]]]`. More generally, you should avoid recommendations about `get` and `assign` in most circumstances. In this case, you already have a named list and can refer to the objects by name as needed.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I should have searched more thoroughly. I didn't think creating a list of global environments would also let us call the variables using that list. @joran, I don't think your solution exists in either of the duplicated posts. Would you want to post that as an answer?